# Is there a faster way to get Amiibo gear

Tags: splatoon-3, amiibo

I have been using Splatoon 3 Amiibos and I want to know if there is a better way to get their presents faster without just playing lots of Turf Wars. Is there a way to get it faster or do I just have to play Turf Wars?

Comment: What do you mean by "faster"? The amiibo say that they need time before giving you another present, and everytime they congratulate about your battling dedication. So no, you just have to play.

Comment: What I meant by "faster" is, due to my low attention span, I often get tired of playing Turf War, so I was wondering if there was another mode I could play, that gets me the same amount of progress. If Turf War is my only option for good progress with Amiibos then I will just battle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've used that amiibo on the same console in Splatoon 2, they'll recognize you and give you every reward for free. Obviously this doesn't work with Smallfry.